# Get all components from a GameObject? including children

Tags: unity

i'm making an Enemy Death, and for that i need to get every CapsuleCollider2D from a specific GameObject, including all his children. What i'm trying to do is create an Array, which every capsule collider, and then destroy everyone when the enemy dies. I've searched through several forums but i didn't got the key. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried? From your description it seems like you should be able to use recursion to go down the children-tree?

Comment: Are you looking for `GetComponentsInChildren<CapsuleCollider2D>()` ?

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry if i' ve forgotten to show which things i tried. I not only want to get components from children, i want to add parent capsule collider too. So, if there is a way to add stuff into an array after using GetComponentsInChildren should be great, because after that line i could add the parent capsule collider component

Answer (score 1):

> What i'm trying to do is create an Array, which every capsule collider, and then destroy everyone when the enemy dies.

This is all you need:

```
var colliders = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>();
foreach (var collider in colliders) {
    collider.enabled = false;
}
```